# Why is my package not detected when attempting to launch application in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two very simple apps. The first app should launch the second app. But I am running into problems.

The first app attempts to launch the second app like this:

```
val launchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.secondapp")
if (launchIntent != null) {
    try {
        startActivity(launchIntent)
        Log.d("", "Launching com.example.secondapp")
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Log.d("", "Failed to launch com.example.secondapp")
    }
} else {
    Log.d("", "Intent is null value.")
}
```

The second app has first line

```
package com.example.secondapp
```

So the package name is correct. Yet the output of launching the first app is:

```
D/: Intent is null value.
```

So for some reason the second app is not being detected.

Any ideas why? Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring, if you are testing on Android 11+.

Comment: on which Android SDK are you performing your test run? @JamesRead

Comment: @KartikAgarwal API 21: Android 5.0 (Lollipop)